# Issues with filtering out rows of a generated table using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to filter out rows of an HTML table based on user input from a dropdown menu. My idea is to remove the rows if the first column of the first row is not equal to the value of the drop down menu. However the only thing I've been able to make it do is either just remove the first column, remove everything, or everything except the first column, depending on how I've messed with the jquery function. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out. The code I'm using is below:
Jquert function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr').show();
        $('#searchBtn').click(function () {
            var weaverSet = $("#weaverSet").val();
            $('tr').each(function () {
                var weaveName = $('td.headerName').text();
                if ($.trim(weaveName) != $.trim(weaverSet)) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Table:

```
<table class="dataTable">
<tr>
    <th>
        WS Name &nbsp;
    </th>
    <th>
        M Number
        <br/>
        Bar Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Start Date
        <br/>
        Start Time
    </th>
    <th>
        Length
        <br/>
        Doff Length
    </th>
    <th>
        Name
        <br/>
        End Time
    </th>
    <th>
        B Number
    </th>
    <th>
        Dynamic Value
    </th>  
</tr>

          <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in MVCMasterDetail.DataAccess.ManTracDataProvider.GetTopData())
    { 

        <tr>
            <td class ="headerName">
                @item.WSName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.MNumber
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.StartDate
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Length
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.bnumber
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DynamicValue
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="99"> //This calls the partial view that renders the detail table inside of it
                @Html.Action("MasterDetailDetailPartial", new { id = item.WorkOrderActualId, LNumber = item.MNumber })

            </td>
        </tr>

    }
             </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not iterate over tds?

```
$('td.headerName').each(function () {
   var weaveName = $(this).text();
   if ($.trim(weaveName) != $.trim(weaverSet)) {
       $(this).parent().next().hide();
       $(this).parent().hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: This one almost works as well. The issue is that the detail rows of the rows that get removed stay. Is there any way to make it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this line:

```
var weaveName = $('td.headerName').text();
```

The selector will return every TD with that class in the page. WHen you try to get a value ( *like text()* ) from a collection of elements, only the value of the first element in collection will be returned.

Within your loop of all the TR you want to look only for `td.headerName` that is in that row. Can use `find()` to do it.

```
$('tr').each(function () {
     /* look for text in this row*/
     var weaveName = $(this).find('td.headerName').text();
     /* no need to trim "weaverset" each time, do it when variable created, saves many function calls*/
     if ($.trim(weaveName) != $.trim(weaverSet)) {
           $(this).hide();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost solved it. One more follow up. I need the detail rows and headers to stay and this gets rid of those. Is there anyway to make it skip over those if it meets the criteria?